# How to get the title of the value from yaml to java

Tags: java, yaml

```
fruits:
    apple:
        color: red
    banana:
        color: yellow
    graps:
        color: purple
```

is it posible to get a String[] with value of {"apple", "banana", "grapes"} in java

i have tried many way but i still cant figure it out

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, Object> obj = yaml.load(inputStream);
obj.values();
```

see also: https://www.baeldung.com/java-snake-yaml